# Is there possible to deploy multiple Nodejs Web API App in single azure app service?

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, nodejs-server, node-api

My requirement is simple.

I already have an one azure app service (https://<app_service>.azurewebsites.net/) and I hosted a NodeJs Web API app under that above mentioned app service. It worked fine when calling the API with specified app service URL(https://<app_service>.azurewebsites.net/).

My virtual path and physical path of the application is like in below image.

[image: virtual path and physical path image]

And this is my NodeJS web API app web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <webSocket enabled="false" />
  
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
  </handlers>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="StaticContent">
        <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
      </rule>

      <rule name="DynamicContent">
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>

  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <remove segment="bin"/>
      </hiddenSegments>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>

  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

And this is my NodeJS web API app index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Call from Node API!!!");
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1660;

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port %s...", server.address().port);
});
```

Now, I want this same NodeJS Web API application with another virtual path with same azure app service.

For e.g.,

(https://<app_service>.azurewebsites.net/nodeapi)

[image: new virtual path]

Is this possible to achieve? If so, could you please tell me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, It is possible to deploy multiple apps under same app service plan. Working on it will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deploy Multiple Web Apps under same App service by using `Import Profile` and Adding Virtual Directories in Azure Portal

Check the below workaround

- Created an App service with Runtime stack Node.
- In the newly created app service add the virtual applications under `Configuration` => `Path Mappings` Section
  [image]
- In the Overview Section of the App service, click on `Get Publish Profile`
  [image]
- In Visual Studio created two `NodeJS` Web Applications
  [image]
- Right click on the first web app and click on publish
  [image]
- Browse and select the PUBLISHSETTINGS file downloaded from `Azure Web App` from portal.
  [image]
- Make sure that you are giving the site name as same. Here it is `NodeSample`.
- Check and verify the name in both places (***Virtual Applications and directories*** in Path Mappings and in **`Publish Settings`**) are same.
- **`Save`** and **`Publish`** the App.
- Now select the second Web App and Continue the same steps to publish using Import Profile.

**Deployed Web Apps folder structure**

[image]

In this case Both the Apps are accessible by using the below URL's
**Ex:**

```cs
https://nodesample.azurewebsites.net/NodejsSample1
https://nodesample.azurewebsites.net/NodejsSample2
```