# how to deploy nodejs app to azure app service in a virtual directory using github action?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

Here is my workflow file api.xml

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - raymultiapp1

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: raymultiapp1/api
          slot-name: 'production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/api
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_bf436910e72f4781a297e902cafb1234 }}
```

the above file is not working, do any one know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please share GitHub repository link if possible (& if there is no sensitive data).

Comment: @PravallikaKV it is private repo, but is it just a hello world level api

Comment: I will check from my end and provide the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a NodeJS application and deployed to Azure App Service (Windows) using GitHub actions:

**Index.js:**

- Add `app.listen(process.env.port);` in your code:

```js
var express = require('express');

var PORT = 8080;

var app = express();
app.get('/api', function (req, res){
  res.send('Hello world, Node.js app running on Docker');
});

app.listen(process.env.port);
console.log('Node.js web server at port 8080 is running..')
```

- ***Created a Windows Azure App Service with Node version 18 as Runtime Stack***.

Add below mentioned application settings in your `App=>Settings=>Environment Variables/Configuration=>App Settings`:

**Application Settings of Web App:**

```
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 18
WEBSITES_PORT = 8080
```

[image]

**GitHub Workflow to deploy Node JS application to Azure:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - APPNAME

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'APPNAME'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_BB0391AXXXXXXXXXF304B }}
```

**Deployment Status in GitHub:**

[image]

Check if all the project files deployed into App Service:

- Navigate to `KUDU site of your app(App=>Advanced Tools=>Go)`, go to `site/wwwroot` and check if all the required files are deployed and available.

**Windows:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

***You can follow the same steps for Linux Web App as well***.

Comment: buy my final target is host the reactjs and nodejs at same instance, so i ask virtual application in windows is possible to do or not. Linux don't have virtual application configuration.

Comment: You can follow the steps I have provided to deploy NodeJS to Windows app =>virtual application(Site/wwwroot/).

Comment: is it possible to deploy to Site/wwwroot/app1 , and app 2 deploy to Site/wwwroot/app2?

Comment: AFIK, when we deploy the application, the project files will be deployed to Site/wwwroot`. To achieve your requirement, I feel you can try pushing the project folder to GIT as shown in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/IOm4u5w.png) and deploy. Then add the projectname in Path Mappings like (site/wwwroot/project1) and (site/wwwroot/project2).

Comment: I will also try this from my end and confirm.

Comment: i tried but not working, seems the git workflow not able to recognize the package.json location when it is located at subfolder

Comment: This seems to be possible if you deploy using visual studio, Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442032/19991670) answer.